# Deserializing the class with Guid is not parsing back the guid value

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I am getting the json from the HttpClient Get Request. the result is deserializing every property except the Guid and Datetime. the Guid properties are parsing as **{System.Guid}** and date is parsing back as **{System.DateTime}**.

Web Request:

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<UserEntity>>(json);
```

Json:

```
[{"Id":"5aee0750-6cd9-4d20-9fe9-1f7e23a4520b","MemberShipUserID":12346,
"Username":"Joshr","EmpName":"Josh","Password":"test123",
"Email":"nanidotnetdev@gmail.com","Phone":"1234567899",
"IsActive":true,"IsContractor":true,"RoleID":null,"ProfilePhotoID":null,
"CreatedDate":"2018-08-08T01:15:12.73",
"CreatedBy":"e4c6d172-3d14-4539-9fee-306b081dc3db","UpdatedDate":null,
"UpdatedBy":null,"LastLoginDate":null}]
```

UserEntity:

```
public class UserEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public int? MemberShipUserID { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public bool IsContractor { get; set; }

        public Guid? RoleID { get; set; }

        public string ProfilePhotoID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        public Guid? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Am I missing any property declarations here? Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should change your class to match your JSON (Id in JSON, UserId in class. CreatedDate parses OK, no other date values are set in your JSON. Voting to close because it seems to be a simple naming mistake. [Example here](http://rextester.com/FFP83792)

Comment: Sorry john. that is a typo. I tried with Id also. But it is not parsing the Guid. I am assuming I might have to do custom parsing for Guid. But not sure how. And Date properties are not parsing back too.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (see example). What version of JSON.NET are you using?

Comment: I am using 11.0.0.0(latest version). Do the backslashes make any difference in the JSON?

Comment: the backslashes are so that I can input it as a string. It just escapes the quotes which would otherwise mark the end of the string in C#. Note that the VS debugger will also show the backslashes unless you click the magnifying glass to see the actual string.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Working for me.

Comment: Just tried with 11.0.2 in C# (the latest version on NuGet) and I can't reproduce - I get the same output as my example link.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will try to change the JSON version and try again.

Comment: Hi Nalluri, I'm using .net framework 4.7, JSON.NET version 11.0.2, CultureInfo en-US and I can't reproduce your situation. Can you see here [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/POk7HK)